# Puppet Master Could not request certificate Permission Denied

Tags: puppet, ubuntu-14.04, puppetmaster, puppet-agent

I have been all over the internet and tried different fixes to which none have worked.

Issue: When setting up a new agent to connect to the Puppet Master I run:

```
sudo /opt/puppetlabs/bin/puppet agent --test
```

The output of this command is (with certain text removed or modified):

```
Info: csr_attributes file loading from /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/csr_attributes.yaml
Info: Creating a new SSL certificate request for puppetmaster.example.com
Info: Certificate Request fingerprint (SHA256): <<intentionally removed>>
Error: Could not request certificate: Error 500 on SERVER: Internal Server Error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/ca/requests/puppetagent.example.com.pem (Permission denied)
Exiting; failed to retrieve certificate and waitforcert is disabled
```

Couple of things I have tried/verified that have not worked:

--I can successfully telnet to the master via DNS name on port 8140

--Just to be sure it wasn't the agent server I tried with another server and have the same issue there.

-- When I use waitforcert is just has the same error over and over.

-- When I do:

```
sudo /opt/puppetlabs/bin/puppet cert list
```

I don't get anything in the list.

I read articles about permissions on the master. Here is a ls -lh of the SSL dir

```
root@puppetmaster:/home/ubuntu# ls -lh /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/
total 28K
drwxr-xr-x 5 root 999 4.0K Jan  2 10:14 ca
drwxr-xr-x 2 root 999 4.0K Jan  2 10:10 certificate_requests
drwxr-xr-x 2 root 999 4.0K Jan  4 08:58 certs
-rw-r--r-- 1 root 999 1.1K Jan  4 08:58 crl.pem
drwxr-x--- 2 root 999 4.0K Jan  2 10:10 private
drwxr-x--- 2 root 999 4.0K Jan  2 10:10 private_keys
drwxr-xr-x 2 root 999 4.0K Jan  2 10:10 public_keys
```

It's obvious what is wrong... the agent can't get the cert to the master so I can't sign the cert at the master. Problem is I am at a complete loss as to what to look at next. Any advise would be very much appreciated.

Thanks !

Comment: Doesn't puppet need write access to the ca/requests directory (and possibly others too)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ownership (user and group) for your `/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl` directory is wrong. The `ssl` directory and its children need to be owned by the `puppet` user and group:

```
chown -R puppet:puppet /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl
```

After fixing the ownership you may need to restart puppetserver:

```
service puppetserver restart
```

Now your puppetserver should be able to issue certificates to Puppet agents.

Comment: Very bizarre.  The first agent I did worked. All is good now. Since the first worked I didn't think to change the dir perms. Sigh.... stared at it too long i guess. Thanks!